# Read local json file in firefox extension

Tags: javascript, json, firefox-addon

I am writing a firefox extension, and want the functionality to upload a local json file and read this file to perform further actions. This json file in simple terms contains a list of urls, which on reading by the plugin will help in highlighting these urls if they are present on the webpage.

As suggested [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/), I am  trying with   tag in extensions panel and then trying to use FileReader to access the content of the file, but unfortunately I am not able to do it.

The code looks like following:

```
<input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="files"/>
```

and

```
 function handleFileSelect(evt){
 /* some code */
    }

 document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect,false);
```

In the javascript code, the 'evt' parameter that is received is empty {}.

**Question:**

1. Is there any other alternative/better approach to read a json file
   in a firefox extension.
2. Why the "evt" parameter is empty in the given case.

Comment: I'm not sure man  I copied pasted your code exactly and in the handle function i put `alert(evt.target.files.length)` and it it works just fine.

Comment: @Noitidart I got the same feedback from one my friend as well. I will look into it again once I get some time. Thanks.

Comment: @Noitidart somehow I am able to read the file and get the desired result, but the event parameter still show empty :(. I will delve into this later and update as per over here. In the meanwhile I will accept your answer. Thanks once again.

Comment: Email me your addon or upload to github and share link with me Ill take a look at it for you. Are you running this from privelaged context? Or are you running in website?

Comment: Please compile your addon to xpi so i can install it right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use FileReader, here is a working example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Noitidart/zTe4j/3/). browse and select a file with json contents and it will parse it and set the global json var to it.

its set up for multiple file select, you can change that easy by removing the `multiple` attribute and adjusting the script for no looping.

or copy paste this into a html file to test it out

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
var json;

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.

}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
            return function (e) {
                console.log('e readAsText = ', e);
                console.log('e readAsText target = ', e.target);
                try {
                    json = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
                    alert('json global var has been set to parsed json of this file here it is unevaled = \n' + JSON.stringify(json));
                } catch (ex) {
                    alert('ex when trying to parse json = ' + ex);
                }
            }
        })(f);
        reader.readAsText(f);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

if like @Noitidart , you find sync read-write yucky, here is code for async read-write:

```
/*start - example usage*/
var file = FileUtils.getFile("Desk", ["rawr.txt"]); //this gets file on desktop named 'rawr.txt'
//can also go: var file = FileUtils.File('C:\\Documents and Settings\\My User Name\\Desktop\\rawr.txt');

overwriteFile(file, 'blah blah blah', function (status) {
   alert('overwrite status == ' + Components.isSuccessCode(status));
});

readFile(file, function (dataReadFromFile, status) {
   alert('file read status == ' + Components.isSuccessCode(status));
   alert('contents of file is:\n' + dataReadFromFile);
});
/*end - example usage*/





Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm");
function overwriteFile(nsiFile, data, callback) {
   //data is data you want to write to file
   //if file doesnt exist it is created
   var ostream = FileUtils.openSafeFileOutputStream(file)
   var converter = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/intl/scriptableunicodeconverter"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableUnicodeConverter);
   converter.charset = "UTF-8";
   var istream = converter.convertToInputStream(data);
   // The last argument (the callback) is optional.
   NetUtil.asyncCopy(istream, ostream, function (status) {
      if (!Components.isSuccessCode(status)) {
         // Handle error!
         alert('error on write isSuccessCode = ' + status);
         return;
      }
      // Data has been written to the file.
      callback(status)
   });
}

function readFile(nsiFile, callback) {
   //you must pass a callback like function(dataReadFromFile, status) { }
   //then within the callback you can work with the contents of the file, it is held in dataReadFromFile
   //callback gets passed the data as string
   NetUtil.asyncFetch(file, function (inputStream, status) {
      //this function is callback that runs on completion of data reading
      if (!Components.isSuccessCode(status)) {
         alert('error on file read isSuccessCode = ' + status);
         return;
      }
      var data = NetUtil.readInputStreamToString(inputStream, inputStream.available());
      callback(data, status);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making a firefox extensions so you have access to more powerful stuff like [OSFile.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File/OS.File_for_the_main_thread)

I would prefer that.

You can use [nsIJSON - decodeFromStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIJSON#decodeFromStream%28%29)

You can also use FileUtils.jsm to read a file here is an indepth example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O#Writing_to_a_file

If you want user to select a file you should probably use nsIFilePicker. Detailed examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIFilePicker?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=nsIFilePicker#Example

Answer (score 0):

Here is a js module to do just that:

```
let EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = [
    'importJSON',
    'exportJSON',
    'readUTF8File',
    'writeUTF8File',
    'nsFile'
];


const Cc = Components.classes;
const Ci = Components.interfaces;

//unused here, only exported
let nsFile = Components.Constructor("@mozilla.org/file/local;1", Ci.nsILocalFile, "initWithPath");


function exportJSON(obj, file, indent){
    if(typeof indent == 'undefined') indent = 0;
    let s = JSON.stringify(obj, null, indent);
    writeUTF8File(file, s, true);
}

function importJSON(file){
    let s = readUTF8File(file);
    return JSON.parse(s);
}


function readUTF8File(file){
    var aFile;
    if(typeof file === 'string'){
        aFile = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIFile);
        aFile.initWithPath(file);
        if (!aFile.exists() || !aFile.isFile()){
            aFile.create(Ci.nsIFile.NORMAL_FILE_TYPE, 0x1FF);
        }
    } else {
        //var aFile.initWithFile(file);
        aFile = file;
    }
    if (!aFile.exists() || !aFile.isFile()){
        return null;
    }       
    var fstream = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/file-input-stream;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIFileInputStream);
    var cstream = Cc["@mozilla.org/intl/converter-input-stream;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIConverterInputStream);
    fstream.init(aFile, -1, 0, 0);
    cstream.init(fstream, "UTF-8", 0, 0);
    var str = {};
    cstream.readString(-1, str); // read the whole file and put it in str.value
    var data = str.value;
    cstream.close(); //this also closes fstream?
    fstream.close(); //needed or not?
    return data;
};

function writeUTF8File(file, data, overwrite){
    if(typeof file === 'string'){
        var aFile = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIFile);
        aFile.initWithPath(file);
        if (!aFile.exists() || !aFile.isFile()){
            aFile.create(Ci.nsIFile.NORMAL_FILE_TYPE, 0x1FF);
        }
    } else {
        //var aFile.initWithFile(file);
        var aFile = file;
    }
    var foStream = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIFileOutputStream);
    var converter = Cc["@mozilla.org/intl/converter-output-stream;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIConverterOutputStream);

    if(overwrite){
        // write|create|truncate
        foStream.init(aFile, 0x02 | 0x08 | 0x20, 0x1B6, 0); 
    }else{
        // write|create|append
        foStream.init(aFile, 0x02 | 0x08 | 0x10, 0x1B6, 0);
    }
    /*
    //write|create : will write to file from start (like taping over a casette!)
    //foStream.init(aFile, 0x02 | 0x08, 0666, 0);*/
    converter.init(foStream, "UTF-8", 0, 0);
    converter.writeString(data);
    converter.close(); // this closes foStream?
    foStream.close();//not needed?
};
```

usage demo:

```
var rwjson={};
Components.utils.import('file:///D:/_VB%20Progs/%5BFirefox%5D/%5BRepository%5D/JSON%20Read-Write%20to%20UTF-8%20File/rwjson.jsm', rwjson);


rwjson.exportJSON( {cool:'me'} , 'c:\\test1.json', 4); //indent=4 spaces
let o = rwjson.importJSON('c:\\test1.json'); //o.cool

//extra stuff
rwjson.writeUTF8File('c:\\cool.txt', 'some text...\n', /*overwrite*/ false);
rwjson.readUTF8File('c:\\cool.txt');

//totally unrelated!
var f = rwjson.nsFile('C:\\cool.txt');
f instanceof Ci.nsILocalFile //true
f instanceof Ci.nsIFile //true
f.exists();
f.isFile();
f.isDirectory();
//f.launch();
//f.reveal();
```